# Can this recursive function take less stack space (without rewriting as a loop)?

Tags: recursion, rust, stack-overflow

I've got some code which is running for a while and then throwing stack overflow errors. Based on the behavior and debugging, I do not think this is a case of infinite recursion, but instead of deep (but finite) and  inefficient recursion.

I'm pretty convinced the following code is to blame:

```
fn get_descendant_leaves(&self, p: Point) -> Vec<Point> {
    let children = self.get_children(p);
    if children.is_empty() {
        vec![p]
    } else {
        children
            .iter()
            .map(|child_p| self.get_descendant_leaves(child_p.0))
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Note the recursive `self.get_descendant_leaves` call. `get_children` is a non-recursive function that does a little work to recompute immediate children based on what's stored at that location (maximum of 8, usually more like 1-3). Don't worry about the self parameter - there is a lot of information hiding behind it, but here it is only needed to compute the children of a given point.

I've found that the above function hits a depth of 2-3k simultaneously from multiple threads immediately before the program crashes, which is why I'm convinced it is to blame.

I'm sure I could fix this by manually re-implementing the function to instead loop with a couple of mutable vectors - one of discovered leaves, and one of non-leaves that still need to be explored. However, I sort of suspect that this is something Rust could do for me, were I only treating it more kindly.

Is there something I could do to represent this to rust in a way that would automatically avoid the growing call stack? I'm wondering if I handled the `flatten` or `collect` differently, maybe rust's `iter` could would automatically handle this in a way similar to the manual solution described above. (My reasoning is that because the recursive call is in a closure that could(?) be called lazily, this seems like something the compiler might be able to unwind on its own.)

(It has to run for an hour or more to grow complex enough to crash, so experimentation is slow.)

Bonus question: Debugging this to this state took me forever, using a mix of `println`s and `lldb`'s `thread backtrace` to see where things were when stuff exploded. What else should have been in my toolkit for investigating this? Googling "how to diagnose rust stack overflow" turned up mostly discouraging results.

**EDIT:** here's a parallel structure to make debugging more fruitful. Similarly to the code above, it recursively explores a tree, building a flattened vector from "leaves" where the base condition is met.

In the example case, the "tree" exists only in theory, but can be though of as a fibbonachi-esque tree where `Tree(i)` has as children `Tree(i-1)` and `Tree(i-2)` for `i >=1`, with `Tree(1)` and `Tree(0)` as leaves.

Can this be done keeping the recursive function definition, but in such a way that Rust does not actually explode the stack in computing it?

```
fn main() {
    let awful = awful_vec_builder(10, 0);
    println!("See it's awful: {:?}", awful);
    println!("Let's smash the stack:");
    let more_awful = awful_vec_builder(5000, 0);
    println!("Please don't reach this case: {}", more_awful.len())
}

fn awful_vec_builder(i: usize, depth: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    if i < 2 {
        vec![depth]
        //Note that using vec![] here still overflows the stack
    } else {
        let v = vec![i - 1, i - 2];
        v.iter()
            .map(|i| awful_vec_builder(*i, depth + 1))
            .flatten()
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Comment: How would calling the closure lazily change anything about the recursion depth?

Comment: As for solutions, if you just want to make it run, you can increase your stack size using `ulimit`. If you want a proper solution, rewrite the code iteratively. a recursion depth of 3k sounds unreasonable to me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach So to answer your laziness question: The function can theoretically return without having called that closure. The closure could then be called at some future point, again lazily returning a structure that includes some number of closures. At no point would any execution of this function then be nested beneath another in the call stack.

Comment: *“I'm sure I could fix this by manually re-implementing the function to instead loop with a couple of mutable vectors”* This is worth trying before going into a rabbit hole and potentially finding out that the cause was something else. It’s about the same number of lines.

Comment: @Ry- So there are two reasons I'm asking rather than doing that. One, testing is a pain, and the stuff I omitted to not bog SO down with unnecessary details makes it a little less trivial a rewrite. Two, and more importantly, I'm trying to gain insight into the workings of Rust, and I think I'll learn more by making this work recursively (or getting a definite answer why it can't.) FWIW, I did due dilligence making sure this is the issue - `lldb` shows a stack trace lousy with `get_descendent_leaves` calls, and printlns showed several threads deeply recursed in this function at once.

Comment: @EdwardPeters I don't think that's possible. If you want to desecent 3k layers deep into a tree, you need a stack to store all the intermediate nodes on some stack. Using recursive code, this stack can only be the call stack. Sure, you could return `impl Iterator<Item = Point>` instead of `Vec<Point>`, and remove the `.collect()`, but that would reduce the maximum recursion depth only by 1.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I was just considering that possibility - why would it only reduce the recursion depth by 1? Assuming I'm correct in understanding that Iterators are lazy, that would mean the recursive call was *never* made before the function returned. Wouldn't that mean that my code never contributed additional stack frames?

Comment: What I said in my previous comment was a bit to simple. Since you have an `if` with two branches in your function, in addition to the changes I mentioned you'd also need a way to dispatch to either of the two cases in the function, e.g. by using `itertools::Either`.

Comment: But it still wouldn't help with the recursion depth. Once you iterate over the iterator returned by the outermost function, you call `.next()` on the outermost `Flatten` instance. This will be an `Either` instance, with either just a single element, or with another `Flatten` instance insde. If you encounter another `Flatten` instance, `.next()` will have to be called on that instance, and so on. The recursion depth will be the same. It's still possible that this saves space on the stack, since you don't need to store the three pointer-sized values for each vector anymore.

Comment: If this were tail recursion, it could be optimised by compilers optimising tail recursion. But it's not tail recursion, and Rust doesn't optmise tail recursion.

Comment: And to explicitly answer you question – yes, no recursive call will be made before your function returns. They all only happen when iterating over the returned iterator. However, that doesn't really help, unless you don't want to iterate over the returned iterator, in which case the whole thing is rather pointless.

Comment: @SvenMarnach So it's Rust's implementation of `flatten` making the recursive calls? Looking at the source that seems possible. My only doubt is that I'm pretty sure I could write an interpreter (ignoring a laundry list of thing like user-defined iterators, thread safety, and everything else that Rust supports) that would evaluate this without a recursive call - for instance, `Flatten.next` *is* tail recursive, so it's certainly possible. (Also, rust supports tail recursion it's just not guaranteed, correct?)

Comment: Please provide a proper [MRE], otherwise we can't play around with your code.

Comment: *"getting a small example that did the same thing without introducing a ton of my own assumptions isn't feasible"* - So how are we supposed to help you? We can't see the other code, so now **we** have to make a bunch of assumptions that, according to what you say here, makes the entire discussion irrelevant ... I'd vote to close due to missing details. There's just really no point in discussing hypotheticals.

Comment: *"I'm pretty convinced the following code is to blame:"* - More than 90% of the time I've heard this it turned out to be wrong, wasting a bunch of our time in the process. Again, please provide an MRE, otherwise this entire question is pointless. If you are incapable of reproducing it with your own custom mocks that make this code compile, then this code is not the reason why it crashes.

Comment: @Finomnis I've edited in what I believe to be parallel behavior as an MRE.

Comment: @EdwardPeters It's a MRE if you actually say what it's supposed to do. From my point of view, it crashes, which is exactly what it's supposed to do. It already says `awful_vec_builder`, and that's what it is. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: @EdwardPeters *"Can this be built"* - can **what** be built? What's the desired output of the `awful_vec_builder` function?

Comment: The problem in your original example is that I don't know what `self` is and it makes absolutely no sense to me that we query a child recursively and then call something on `self` with it again. Your second example doesn't contain a tree, so I have absolutely no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: @Finomnis I've edited in additional explanation of the example. If you need there to be an actual tree-as-data I can provide that (though it takes some work as the tree growth itself cannot be recursive), but this is actually a closer fit to the original, as children are computed in the recursive call rather than being natively pre-defined.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Your example makes much more sense with an actual explanation now. However, are you sure that the **result** of `awful_vec_builder(5000,0)` actually fits on the stack?

Comment: @Finomnis yes. It's a `Vec`, so it's heap allocated. :) (I checked that even making the base case empty, so the result is trivial in both heap and stack, still smashes the stack - see the commented line in the latest edit.)

Comment: `vec![]` and `Vec::new()` are identical. I'm talking about the `map`/`flatten`/`collect` calls. I'm not sure how much stack usage they cause.

What's the reason to avoid something iterative? Like, an actual iterator?

Comment: @EdwardPeters This crashes as well, just fyi: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41cb2a25394f65e5eb061e0cc0b359f1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251604/discussion-between-finomnis-and-edward-peters).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm trying to test what you're saying about returning an iterator, but I'm struggling to make something that compiles. I have a much simpler example in the question now, can you show me how to tweak that to return an Iterator?

Comment: Does it stack overflow only in debug mode or in release mode too?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Both. BTW, I did eventually get one that returns an `Iterator` put together, and it behaves as predicted from the comments - the function I wrote does not run recursively, but the `Iterator` machinery causes it to be called at progressively deeper stack frames anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest problem in your implementation is the repeated `flatten` and `collect` calls. Why do those? You basically re-construct the vector in every single call.

Instead, pass the result vector through and write directly into it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let awful = awful_vec_builder(10, 0);
    println!("See it's awful: {:?}", awful);
    println!("Let's smash the stack:");
    let more_awful = awful_vec_builder(5000, 0);
    println!("Please don't reach this case: {}", more_awful.len())
}

fn awful_vec_builder(i: usize, depth: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    fn awful_vec_builder_impl(i: usize, depth: usize, result: &mut Vec<usize>) {
        if i < 2 {
            result.push(depth);
        } else {
            let v = vec![i - 1, i - 2];
            for i in v {
                awful_vec_builder_impl(i, depth + 1, result);
            }
        }
    }
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    awful_vec_builder_impl(i, depth, &mut result);
    result
}
```

```
See it's awful: [9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5]
Let's smash the stack:

... hangs for a really long time ...
```

---

For your first example, here is some boilerplate code that makes it actually compile and crash, as specified:

```rust
fn main() {
    let tree = Tree;
    let awful = tree.get_descendant_leaves(Point { i: 10, depth: 0 });
    println!("See it's awful: {:?}", awful);
    println!("Let's smash the stack:");
    let more_awful = tree.get_descendant_leaves(Point { i: 5000, depth: 0 });
    println!("Please don't reach this case: {}", more_awful.len())
}

struct PointWrapper(Point);

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    i: usize,
    depth: usize,
}

struct Tree;

impl Tree {
    fn get_children(&self, p: Point) -> Vec<PointWrapper> {
        if p.i < 2 {
            vec![]
        } else {
            vec![
                PointWrapper(Point {
                    i: p.i - 1,
                    depth: p.depth + 1,
                }),
                PointWrapper(Point {
                    i: p.i - 2,
                    depth: p.depth + 1,
                }),
            ]
        }
    }

    fn get_descendant_leaves(&self, p: Point) -> Vec<Point> {
        let children = self.get_children(p);
        if children.is_empty() {
            vec![p]
        } else {
            children
                .iter()
                .map(|child_p| self.get_descendant_leaves(child_p.0))
                .flatten()
                .collect()
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to my other example, you could fix it like this:

```rust
fn get_descendant_leaves(&self, p: Point) -> Vec<Point> {
    fn get_descendant_leaves_impl(this: &Tree, p: Point, result: &mut Vec<Point>) {
        let children = this.get_children(p);
        if children.is_empty() {
            result.push(p);
        } else {
            for child_p in children {
                get_descendant_leaves_impl(this, child_p.0, result);
            }
        }
    }

    let mut result = Vec::new();
    get_descendant_leaves_impl(self, p, &mut result);
    result
}
```

---

That said, if there is a recursive solution, there is always a better iterative solution.

Like this one:

```rust
fn get_descendant_leaves(&self, p: Point) -> Vec<Point> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();

    let mut queue = Vec::new();
    queue.push(p);

    while let Some(p) = queue.pop() {
        let children = self.get_children(p);
        if children.is_empty() {
            result.push(p);
        } else {
            queue.extend(children.into_iter().map(|child| child.0).rev())
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Comment: I like it, though I'm still curious about the "Return an Iterator" version. That said, I spent some time trying to work that out myself and now my computer won't boot up, so your method may win by technical knockout.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Added a fix for the first example

Comment: @EdwardPeters Could be that iterators are not powerful enough in Rust yet. This is all about stack frame size; changing the code reduces the stack frame size from almost 2000 to a couple of hundred. This means it still won't recurse further than maybe 30-40k, but at least further than 5k. I'm pretty sure that involving iterators will create a larger stack frame.

Comment: There's just simply no way around that fact: A recursion depth of 5000 will cause a stack usage of 5000*stackframesize. Don't do recursion.

Comment: well, it isn't actually recursing, is the thing. As stated in the question's discussion, if you return a closure that makes the recursive call, one execution of your function returns before the next one ever starts - you have only one stack frame. The problem is that it's been passed off to another system, which may itself be making recursive calls to evaluate the structure - but you can also non-recursively handle a recursive structure (i.e., handle everything in a loop). If I ever get my computer working I'll code an example.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense ... at some point you have to actually recurse. If you return a closure, then the recursion will happen in the closures ... I mean, it has to happen somewhere. At the point where you query the closure, the closure recurses ... and calls the next closure. There will be a recursion.

Comment: Like, if you return an iterator that contains a closure. At some point the iterator will have to produce an item. That's when it will call the closure, which in turn will query the next iterator, which again calls the closure. You just added an indirection; but recursion will happen.

Comment: The closure will run repeatedly, but it will never run in a stack frame beneath itself, is my point - when you run the closure, you just get back another closure. A loop can then handle that as many times as needed, never producing more than a fixed number of stack frames at once.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Not sure. Either way, sounds like an awefully complicated way of creating an iterative solution. I added a simple one to my answer.

Comment: @EdwardPeters here's an iterator solution: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1aecf9df226958d4a3956593db87b189

Comment: So to illustrate what I mean about it not being real recursion, check out https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c0ae7ae554fdff64bdaad3b1b15cdff - there, `tramp_example` *looks* recursive at first glance, but if you look at the order of the printlns and the general code, it doesn't actually generate more than a trivial number of stack frames at once. It would be much harder, but I think you could build an `Iterator` system that had the same sort of behavior behind the scenes.

Comment: As for "That said, if there is a recursive solution, there is always a better iterative solution." - I would omit the word "better". In these simple examples it's true, but I would say that recursion composes much better - you can combine lots of different sorts of calls with different inputs, which becomes a pain when trying to do everything in a loop.

Comment: @EdwardPeters In any more serious project, recursion will be forbidden - due to the fact that you cannot completely reliably guarantee that no stack overflow will ever happen. It's even part of coding standards [like MISRA](https://pvs-studio.com/en/docs/warnings/v2565/). So it's good practice to avoid it in general.

Comment: And yes, I stand to the word **better**. I've taught computer science, and it's surprising how many people struggle with thinking recursively, or in math, understanding complete induction. If you work in a team with more than one person (which would be a pretty lonely team), then recursion is one of those things that is quite hard for a subset of programmers. So again, best practices, avoid recursion.

Comment: The only advantage recursion has is that there is a small number of problems (like satisfying the borrow checker on tree structures) where recursion is actually significantly easier. But performance-wise, it's almost always slower than the iterative version.

Comment: So again, composability. We both know how to translate a recursive function to a loop - now do it when you have ten or twenty different functions calling one another with different inputs. What could be relatively readable recursive code becomes very difficult to understand or wrangle with loops.

Comment: Recursion is extremely common in the FP world - I mentioned writing interpreters? One of the ones I've written was for a language that did not have iterative constructs in its IR, at all. You can still achieve stack safety in such a context, albeit with greater difficulty (and yes, a performance hit.) I wouldn't expect Rust to have that across the board, but specifically having such patterns for flattened iterators wouldn't seem outside the realm of possibility.

Comment: I agree, recursion and the visitor pattern is very common in compilers/lexers/parsers etc.

Comment: That not-real-recursion trick with closures is pretty cool, though, not gonna lie. But now this discussion went on long enough, SO is not for casual discussions. Let's end it here.